# How to create a url that has a string parameter using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, parameter-passing, url-routing

I am looking to show one of two modals that are on one template file. The modals are displaying correctly based on a url string parameter (status=1 or status=0).  I want to create a url in the form **`example.com/page?status=1`**
I have two buttons on another page with code as below:

**`<a href="{% url 'myapp.views.myview' %}">MyDisplayText</a>`**

How can I add my status=1 string to the url being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add the text:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp.views.myview' %}?status=1/0">MyDisplayText</a>
```

if your value is coming from the template context, then output the variable:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp.views.myview' %}?status={{ status }}">MyDisplayText</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this has worked out excellently. I actually went back to the design of the whole app (on paper no less!) I have finished coding this and its working perfectly.